# Confusion about convergent sequences getting mapped to convergent sequences by a continuous function.

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, continuity

In the exercises of Abbott's Understanding Analysis, we are asked to provide an example or a justification for the following claims:

1. A continuous function $f : (0 ,1) \to R$ and a Cauchy sequence $(x_n)$ such that $f(x_n)$ is not a Cauchy sequence.
2. A continuous function $f : [0 ,∞) → R$ and a Cauchy sequence $(x_n)$ such that  $f(x_n)$ is not a Cauchy sequence.

Considering it true that a continuous function maps convergent sequences to convergent sequences and that a sequence in $\mathbb{R}$ is convergent iff it is Cauchy, I thought that both the claims are false.

For the second claim, I argued that since $f$ is continuous, for a sequence $(x_n)$ converging to $x$, $f(x_n)$ converges to $f(x)$. Because $f(x_n)$ converges, $f(x_n)$ is Cauchy.

But it turns out that the first claim has a valid example according to the solutions. $f(x) = 1/x$ on $(0, 1)$ and consider $(x_n) = 1/n$. Clearly, $f(x_n)$ is not convergent and hence not Cauchy.

Why is it that a convergent sequence is not being mapped to a convergent sequence? Does this have something to do with the domain being open or closed?

Comment: $(0,1)$ is not a **complete** metric space.

Comment: So is the correct statement as follows? In a complete metric space,  a continuous function maps a convergent sequence to a convergent sequence.

Comment: In **any** metric space, a continuous function always maps convergent sequences to convergent sequences.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand. Then why is it not the case with the sequence in (0, 1)? You said that it's not complete.

Comment: That's right: $(0,1)$ is not complete.

Comment: Can I say that all the sequences converging in a given metric space will be mapped to convergent sequences in the other metric space?

Comment: I think you need the precise statement of the theorem. Please see an edit to my answer.

Comment: In some spaces, Cauchy sequences fail to converge because the limit point is "missing", like $x_n=1/n$ in $(0,1)$ or $f_n = x^n$ in $C([0,1])$. In these instances, you can "complete" the metric space by adding all of the missing limits of these non-convergent Cauchy sequences, like taking the closure of $(0,1)$ to get $[0,1]$. The trick here is that $f(x)=1/x$ is not defined at zero, so $f(1/n)=n \rightarrow \infty$. The function $1/x$ would not be continuous on the completion of $[0,1]$, even though it is continuous on $(0,1)$, and that is how you break the meta-theorem you might have in mind

Comment: I mean the completion of $(0,1)$, not $[0,1]$, sorry for the typo.

Answer (score 1):

"A continuous map of metric spaces takes convergent sequences to convergent sequences". Let's write the precise statement of this:

> Theorem $1$: Let $f: X \to Y$ be a continuous function of metric spaces. If $(s_n)$
> is a sequence in $X$, **converging to $x_0 \in X$**, then $(f(s_n))$
> is a sequence in $Y$ converging to $f(x_0)$.

In the setting of your first claim, we have a continuous function $f: X \to Y$ with $X = (0, 1)$ and $Y = \mathbf{R}$.

Sure $(x_n) = 1/n$ is a sequence in $X$ for any positive integer $n$. However, $(x_n)$ converges to $0$ which is **not in** $X$. So Theorem 1 above does not hold.